# Connecting two bots with DirectLine javascript

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

this is my scenario:

- **Bot A** (made with *BotFramework-sdk* for Javascript(Node.js)) who receives audio files, calls to *Speech Services REST API* and get the text from it.
- **Bot B** (made with *BotFrameworkComposer*) who has the qna functionality.

I need to set **Bot A** as a *proxy* receiving the audio attatchments and asking to **Bot B** showing the returning answer inside **Bot A**.

I've already managed to connect those two bots with directline and my problem comes after the conversation is started: in **Bot A** i'm using the **REST API** for send messages and **websocket** to receive the activities using the **streamURL**.

After i create the websocket i call for *on message* event to get the messages comming from the **Bot B** but i need to show them using `await context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.text...`

```
            [...]
            response = await axios.post(url, null, config);
            ws = new WebSocket(response.data.streamUrl);

            ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
              [...]
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look over the [80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot) sample for guidance on how to connect two bots. The sample demonstrates a "root bot" (your Bot A) calling the "skill bot" (your Bot B) and executing a dialog before returning control back to the root bot. The conversation Id is maintained across the root and skill bot by use of the `SkillConversationIdFactory`.

Reference the [Implement a skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/skill-implement-skill?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs) docs for additional information on setting up and consuming a skill.